# How can I put JSON return in an array?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm a android beginner and I'm doing to access a JSON file in and it has an error. I have a problem in parsing this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray accounts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("account_data");
    for(int i=0;i < accounts.length();i++){
        JSONObject a = accounts.getJSONObject(i);
        sin = a.getString("sin");
        account_name = a.getString("account_name");
        address = a.getString("address");
        status = a.getString("status");
        due_date = a.getString("due_date");
        total_amount = a.getDouble("total_amount");

        sin_lbl.setText(a.getString("account_name"));
    }
```

here is the JSON File

```
{"account_data":{
    "sin":"200111-102 ",
    "account_name":"LUMABAN, CRISTOM ",
    "address":"352 MABINI ST.,, SABANG, Baliwag ",
    "status":"A ",
    "due_date":"2019-04-23",
    "total_amount":"491.00"
},"code":1101,"message":"Account Info Retrieved"}
```

I have an error in putting it in array.

Comment: What is the error, specifically?

Comment: account_data is not a jsonArray why are you calling getJsonArray()? you need `getJsonObject("account_data")`

Comment: `JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: how can i loop getJsonObject("account_data') and get each data?

Answer (score 0):

if you asked about iterating on json object you could try this one

```
 JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
 JSONObject  menu = jObject.getJSONObject("account_data");
 Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
 Iterator iter = menu.keys();
 while(iter.hasNext()){
   String key = (String)iter.next();
   String value = menu.getString(key);
   map.put(key,value);
 }
```

so now you have your data into as pair of key and value

if you have a json array of this response you could do as following

```
 JSONObject root = new JSONObject("your root");
 JSONArray resultArray = root.getJSONArray("your array key");
 for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
     // here to get json object one by one and access every item into it 
     JSONObject resultObject = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
     posterPath = resultObject.getString("key");
     title = resultObject.getString("key");
     releaseDate = resultObject.getString("key");
     description = resultObject.getString("key");
     voteAverage = resultObject.getDouble("key");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `JSONArray` , try to use `JSONObject`.

```
String[] array = {json.get("sin"), json.get("account_name"), json.get("address"), json.get("status"), json.get("due_date"), json.get("total_amount") }
```

Answer (score 0):

> {"account_data":{"sin":"200111-102 ","account_name":"LUMABAN, CRISTOM ","address":"352 MABINI ST.,, SABANG, Baliwag ","status":"A ","due_date":"2019-04-23","total_amount":"491.00"},"code":1101,"message":"Account Info Retrieved"}

Actually, it's a json object, not array. So that you can not convert json object to json array
Difference between Json Array and Json Object:

1. A JSONArray is an ordered sequence of values. A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs.
2. JSONArray: Its external text form is a string wrapped in square brackets with commas separating the values.
   JSONObject: Its external form is a string wrapped in curly braces with colons between the names and values, and commas between the values and names.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this json parshing

```
try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONObject accounts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("account_data");

            sin = accounts.getString("sin");
            account_name = accounts.getString("account_name");
            address = accounts.getString("address");
            status = accounts.getString("status");
            due_date = accounts.getString("due_date");
            total_amount = accounts.getDouble("total_amount");

            sin_lbl.setText(a.getString("account_name"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```